# Problema con CheckBox en JTable - Java

Tags: java, java-swing, jtable, checkbox, boolean

Quiero resolver un pequeño problema que tengo sobre un proyecto en java y es que tengo un checkbox en una tabla pero el solo me muestra el valor true o false, quiero que me muestre su checkbox correspondiente alguien sabe como puedo solucionarlo.[image: Ver imagen abajo]

```
while (rs.next()) {
                Object[] filas = new Object[CantidadColumnas];
                filas[0] = rs.getObject(1);
                filas[1] = rs.getObject(2);
                filas[2] = rs.getObject(3);
                filas[3] = formato0d.format(rs.getObject(4));
                filas[4] = rs.getObject(5);
                filas[5] = formato2d.format(rs.getObject(6));
                JCheckBox checkbox = new checkBoxPrueba();
                if (rs.getBoolean(7)){
                    checkbox.setSelected(true);
                }else{
                    checkbox.setSelected(false);
                }
                filas[6] = checkbox;
                //filas[6] = new JCheckBox().setSelected(true);
                modelo1.addRow(filas);
            }
```

Comment: De qué tipo es `rs`? puedes mostrar como inicializas y añades a la tabla el `modelo1`?

Comment: @Sebastian Salazar Podrias mostrar el codigo donde creas la tabla

Comment: Para que la `JTable` te ponga `JCheckboxes` no tienes por que crearlos. Prueba poniendo `filas[6] = rs.getBoolean(7)` ya que eso devuelve un `Boolean` y es autoamaticamente convertido en Checkbox

Comment: Que modelo estas utilizando para tu la creación  de tu tabla?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para agregar los `checkBox` a una `jTable`  `getColumn(6)` lo puedes cambiar por el numero de tu columna, esto lo puedes poner donde creas la `jTable`

```
TableColumn tc = tblDetail.getColumnModel().getColumn(6);
tc.setCellEditor(tblDetail.getDefaultEditor(Boolean.class));
tc.setCellRenderer(tblDetail.getDefaultRenderer(Boolean.class));
```